# Cause: org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/DefaultMavenFactory

Tags: java, android, maven

I imported a project to android studio and it was loading and then it gave me an error [this is the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqajR.png)

please help me out with this so my imported project should work properly and my sdk and everything is updated i am using android studio version 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following buildscript repository and dependency

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3'
    }
}
```

Comment: i add this buildscript and tried again but it is still giving me the same error